# Flexislider remove nav arrows on first and last slides

Tags: javascript, navigation, slider

I have been searching all day and havn't been able to find anything that has helped me out.

I am using Flexislider and trying to remove the previous link on first slide and the next link on last slide.

I have even wrapped my first and last slides in a div to separate them from the other slides.

Heres my website: http://www.thisiseloise.co.uk/Mobile/

Here is my code atm but it's not working:

```
    $('#first').flexslider({
    start: function(){
     var active_rel = $(this).find('.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev').css('display:none');
    },

  });

   $('#last').flexslider({
    end: function(){
     var active_rel = $(this).find('.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev').css('display:none');
    },

  });
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Some live example would be much appreciated :) It helps if you facilitate the community

Comment: Ah sorry I thought I put that in! :p

Heres my website with the slider [link] (http://www.thisiseloise.co.uk/Mobile/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this mechanism:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: 'fade',
    controlsContainer: '.flexslider',
    start: function() {
        // 
    },
    end: function() {
    //
    }
});
```

---

Sorry for the text below, I forgot to read your code >.< (what you already had)

---

A quick googlesearch lead me to this site: [FlexSlider API](https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/wiki/FlexSlider-Properties)

Here you can see that you can hook to:

Property, Default, Description

1. start.....Fires when the slider loads the first slide.
2. end......Fires when the slider reaches the last slide (asynchronous).
3. before..Fires asynchronously with each slider animation.

So what you can do is something like:

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: 'fade',
    controlsContainer: '.flexslider'
}).before(function() {
    // Reset before each slide (cheap operation so it's no biggie to call everytime)
    $(".flex-direction-nav").removeClass("firstActive lastActive");
}).start(function() {
    // 
    $(".flex-direction-nav").addClass("firstActive");
}).end(function() {
    //
    $(".flex-direction-nav").addClass("lastActive");
});
```

And CSS:

```
.flex-direction-nav.firstActive, .flex-direction-nav.lastActive {
    opacity: 0;  // You can think about how to hide it, with transition or sth.
}
```

What I would further suggest is to use IDs (possibly instead of classes - or both), as a good practise.